What are the most efficient algorithms for detecting cycles in a directed graph?
I am working on a problem where I need to detect cycles in a directed graph. The graph is represented using an adjacency list, and it can have a large number of nodes and edges. I am looking for the most efficient algorithm to detect cycles, considering both time complexity and space complexity. I have come across several approaches, such as Depth-First Search (DFS) and Kahn's algorithm, but I am not sure which is the best fit for my scenario.
I have implemented the basic DFS approach, where I maintain a recursion stack to detect back edges, which indicate a cycle. The algorithm works for small graphs, but as the size of the graph increases, I notice a significant drop in performance. Additionally, I tried using Kahn's algorithm for topological sorting, but I am not confident if it's the best approach for all types of graphs, especially those with a large number of nodes.
I expected the DFS approach to be efficient enough for larger graphs, but the performance issues suggest that it might not be the best approach in my case. I am looking for guidance on whether there are more efficient algorithms or optimizations that I can apply to my existing approach. Specifically, I would like to know if there are any techniques to reduce the time complexity or handle large graphs more effectively.

If it's not too much trouble, you could implement all the algorithms, measure which one that fits best on the different sizes of your data sets - and then in runtime decide which one to use based on the size of the dataset at hand.

Both Kahn's algorithm and DFS should be O(|V+E|) in time and O(V) in space... if you do it right.  Your words about DFS for large graphs indicate that you didn't do it right.
